What does "Mean field" really mean (across domains)?
I have a terminology question about the use of the phrase "mean-field", coming from someone in control. Other examples of "mean-field" objects include

mean-field physics
mean-field control
mean-field approximation (variational inference)

If I ask someone why "mean-field" is being used in a particular context, it typically ties back to mean-field physics. Some of these applications seem to clash more than I am comfortable with, which points to some sort of understanding on my part which I wish to rectify.
In a mean-field approximation in statistical mechanics [1]:

The mean-field approach is a crude (!) approximation for understanding the behavior of interacting systems. In this caricature, we assume that every single particle in the system only experiences the average behavior of its neighbors.

In a mean-field approximation in variational inference (which I have only personally worked with in MRFs) [2][3]:

This setup is a fairly general, however we can also partition the latent variables $z_1,\ldots, z_m$ into $R$ groups $z_{G_1},\ldots , z_{G_R}$ , and use the approximation:
$$q(z_1, \ldots, z_R) = q(z_{G_1},\ldots , z_{G_R}) = \prod_{r = 1}^R q(z_{G_r})$$
This is often called “generalized mean field” as compared to “naive mean field” [which is later stated on page 11 to be assuming that all vertices in the MRF are independent]

So already we have a difference in interpretation that, in the first, we depend only on our neighbors, and in the second that we depend only on ourselves.
In McKean-Vlasov equations [4]:

[The McKean-Vlasov process] is an example of propagation of chaos, in that it can be obtained as a limit of a mean-field system of interacting particles: as the number of particles tends to infinity, the interactions between any single particle and the rest of the pool will only depend on the particle itself

However, the McKean-Vlasov equation's coefficients have dependence on the solution (i.e., the density of all agents), so how are we only dependent on our own position/controller/strategy if there is a dependence on the global solution?
In a mean-field game, I get the intuition that, because there are so many agents, I assume that my choices impact others' strategies (and therefore the global solution) very little, so I can solve my optimization problem assuming everyone elses' strategies are fixed. That seems to be the interpretation of mean-field in McKean-Vlasov above. My loss is still dependent on the entire density of the problem, in other words I have some global dependence on all others' actions, so it seems wrong to say I am independent of all other agents. However, (assuming they are optimal/we are in a Nash-type situation) I understand how I can edit my strategy without assuming that others will change their strategy, and so I don't impact the density, and so that part of my loss is fixed. In other words, it seems like there are multiple notions of independence and mean-field flying around here, and so I would welcome any help trying to see how these definitions are (or maybe aren't) similar. Thanks for any advice people can provide!

As an applied mathematician who works in "mean-field" interacting particle systems, I am happy to answer this particular question via Zoom (you can reach me out via email listed in my profile), if you like.
